# Docker + Java + OpenCV, no opencv_java342 in java.library.path

Tags: java, docker, opencv, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to generate a docker image with the following characteristics

- **SO** --> ubuntu:18.04
- **Java** --> openjdk-11-jdk
- **OpenCV** --> 3.4.2 version

I am able to generate the images successfully but the java342 file is not generated in the lib folder, I am getting this exception: **no opencv_java342 in java.library.path**

I am launching my app using the following command as entrypoint:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/var/lib/opencv-3.4.2/build/lib -jar Application.jar
```

**Log Output**

```
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java342 in java.library.path: [/var/lib/opencv-3.4.2/build/lib]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1303) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202) ~[spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.6.RELEASE]
        at com.etaluma.oem.controller.camera.CameraServerApplication.main(CameraServerApplication.java:11) ~[classes!/:0.8.11-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:47) ~[CameraServerSimulator.jar:0.8.11-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:86) ~[CameraServerSimulator.jar:0.8.11-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[CameraServerSimulator.jar:0.8.11-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) ~[CameraServerSimulator.jar:0.8.11-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.etaluma.oem.controller.camera.CameraServerImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java342 in java.library.path: [/var/lib/opencv-3.4.2/build/lib]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1295) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java342 in java.library.path: [/var/lib/opencv-3.4.2/build/lib]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2660) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:829) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1867) ~[na:na]
        at com.etaluma.oem.controller.camera.CameraServerImpl.<init>(CameraServerImpl.java:24) ~[classes!/:0.8.11-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172) ~[spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
```

**Docker File**

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y ant
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk
ARG JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
ENV JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
RUN echo $JAVA_HOME
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN apt-get install -y cmake
RUN apt-get install -y g++
RUN apt-get install -y unzip
RUN apt-get install -y vim
RUN java -version

RUN wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/3.4.2.zip
RUN unzip 3.4.2.zip -d /var/lib/
RUN mkdir /var/lib/opencv-3.4.2/build
WORKDIR /var/lib/opencv-3.4.2/build
RUN cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..
RUN make -j8
```

**Docker File System**
[image]

**General configuration from the OpenCV compilation process**

```
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.4.2 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
--
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2019-10-07T00:32:28Z
--     Host:                        Linux 4.9.184-linuxkit x86_64
--     CMake:                       3.10.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               Release
--
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
--       requested:                 SSE3
--     Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       SSE4_1 (3 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1
--       SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
--       FP16 (2 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
--       AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
--       AVX2 (9 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
--       AVX512_SKX (1 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_SKX
--
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
--     C++11:                       YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 7.4.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):
--     Linker flags (Debug):
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
--     Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
--     3rdparty dependencies:       ittnotify libprotobuf zlib libjpeg-turbo libwebp libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf ippiw ippicv
--
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann highgui imgcodecs imgproc java_bindings_generator ml objdetect photo python_bindings_generator shape stitching superres ts video videoio videostab
--     Disabled:                    js world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java python2 python3 viz
--     Applications:                tests perf_tests apps
--     Documentation:               NO
--     Non-free algorithms:         NO
--
--   GUI:
--     GTK+:                        NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
--
--   Media I/O:
--     ZLib:                        build (ver 1.2.11)
--     JPEG:                        libjpeg-turbo (ver 1.5.3-62)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
--     PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.34)
--     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.9)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
--     HDR:                         YES
--     SUNRASTER:                   YES
--     PXM:                         YES
--
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394:                      NO
--     FFMPEG:                      NO
--       avcodec:                   NO
--       avformat:                  NO
--       avutil:                    NO
--       swscale:                   NO
--       avresample:                NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     libv4l/libv4l2:              NO
--     v4l/v4l2:                    linux/videodev2.h
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
--
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads
--
--   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
--
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Intel IPP:                   2017.0.3 [2017.0.3]
--            at:                   /var/lib/opencv-3.4.2/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx
--     Intel IPP IW:                sources (2017.0.3)
--               at:                /var/lib/opencv-3.4.2/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippiw_lnx
--     Lapack:                      NO
--     Eigen:                       NO
--     Custom HAL:                  NO
--     Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
--
--   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
--     Include path:                /var/lib/opencv-3.4.2/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
--
--   Python (for build):            NO
--
--   Java:
--     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.10.5)
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/include
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
--
--   Matlab:                        NO
--
--   Install to:                    /usr/local
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /var/lib/opencv-3.4.2/build
```

So I would like to know if I am missing something in the docker file or in the openCV compilation process.

Note: If I execute the same process in a native machine everything works as expected

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried building OpenCV with [BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.html)?

Comment: Yes, I already tried with BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON and behaves in the same way

Comment: @GustavoPonce - did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `libopencv_java342.so` file from `/usr/local/lib` to `/usr/lib`.

If the `.so` files are not generated, try this:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..
```

Comment: also if .so files are not generated, please try this

Comment: cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I notice from your post two things that are missing

1. In the OpenCV Compilation process file, in the section "OpenCV modules: To be built: ", I don't see java. According to the official documentation java must be there.

> Examine the output of CMake and ensure java is one of the modules "To be built". If not, it's likely you're missing a dependency.

2. I don't see Python in your Dockerfile and you need it. This is requirement mentioned in the official doc.

> In order to build OpenCV with Java bindings you need JDK (Java Development Kit) (we recommend Oracle/Sun JDK 6 or 7), Apache Ant and Python v2.6 or higher to be installed.

I used this line

```
RUN apt-get install -y python3.8
```

Curiously, when I added python, java was included in the "OpenCV modules to be built"

Answer (score 0):

**Open CV 4.8 with Java**

- This Docker file downloads source and builds an OpenCV in a Debian
  container
- Image contains the Java Jar (opencv-480.jar) and the corresponding share libs (libopencv_java480.so). These are needed for Java <> OpenCV interop
- All transitive dependent .so libs are copied into the `opencvlibs` dir. If you are deploying on Debian linux, copy the contents of `opencvlibs` to your `libs` dir. Linux will then find them by convention

Running with Java:

- The Jar must be on classpath
- The .so must be specified via `java.library.path`

Docker file:

```
FROM debian:11 AS opencv-libs

# Install minimal prerequisites (Ubuntu 18.04 as reference)
# Build tools for OpenCV
# libavcodec, libavformat, libswscale, libavutil, libswresample are needed by ffmpeg. See https://ffmpeg.org/about.html
RUN apt update && \
apt install \
cmake build-essential g++ openjdk-17-jdk wget unzip ant python3 python3-numpy \
libtbb-dev libeigen3-dev \
libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libavutil-dev libswresample-dev liblzma-dev \
ffmpeg libpulse0 -y

# Download and unpack OpenCV sources
# Note that the Java jar version must match the version we build here - 4.8 at the moment
RUN wget -O opencv.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.x.zip && unzip opencv.zip

# Create build directory
RUN mkdir -p build && cd build

# Configure OpenCV. Turn off features we do not need to restrict size
# See: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/d05/tutorial_config_reference.html
#
# CMAKE OUTPUT, MUST LOOK LIKE SHOWN BELOW:
# Important things to note:
# - Java/ant/JNI are enabled under Java:
# - FFMPEG is enabled under Video I/O:
#
# CMAKE OUTPUT #################################################################################################################################
#11 28.73 --   OpenCV modules:
#11 28.74 --     To be built:                 calib3d core features2d flann gapi imgcodecs imgproc java objdetect photo stitching video videoio
#11 28.74 --     Disabled:                    dnn highgui ml world
#11 28.74 --     Disabled by dependency:      -
#11 28.74 --     Unavailable:                 python2 python3 ts
#11 28.74 --     Applications:                -
#11 28.74 --     Documentation:               NO
#11 28.74 --     Non-free algorithms:         NO
#11 28.74 --
#11 28.74 --   GUI:
#11 28.74 --     GTK+:                        NO
#11 28.74 --     VTK support:                 NO
#11 28.74 --
#11 28.74 --   Media I/O:
#11 28.74 --     ZLib:                        zlib (ver 1.2.13)
#11 28.74 --     JPEG:                        libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.1.3-62)
#11 28.74 --     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020f)
#11 28.74 --     PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
#11 28.74 --     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.2.0)
#11 28.74 --     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 2.5.0)
#11 28.74 --     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
#11 28.75 --     HDR:                         YES
#11 28.75 --     SUNRASTER:                   YES
#11 28.75 --     PXM:                         YES
#11 28.75 --     PFM:                         YES
#11 28.75 --
#11 28.75 --   Video I/O:
#11 28.75 --     DC1394:                      NO
#11 28.75 --     FFMPEG:                      YES
#11 28.75 --       avcodec:                   YES (58.91.100)
#11 28.75 --       avformat:                  YES (58.45.100)
#11 28.75 --       avutil:                    YES (56.51.100)
#11 28.75 --       swscale:                   YES (5.7.100)
#11 28.75 --       avresample:                NO
#11 28.75 --
#...
#11 28.76 --   Java:
#11 28.76 --     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.10.9)
#11 28.76 --     Java:                        NO
#11 28.76 --     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/include /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/include
#11 28.76 --     Java wrappers:               YES (ANT)
#11 28.76 --     Java tests:                  NO
# ########################################################################################################################################################

# OpenCV build needs JDK
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64

RUN cmake -DWITH_GSTREAMER=OFF \
-DBUILD_opencv_highgui=OFF \
-DBUILD_opencv_dnn=OFF \
-DBUILD_opencv_ml=OFF \
-DBUILD_opencv_apps=OFF \
-DBUILD_opencv_js=OFF \
-DBUILD_opencv_ts=OFF \
-DBUILD_opencv_viz=OFF \
-DBUILD_opencv_lagacy=OFF \
-DBUILD_opencv_androidcamera=OFF \
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF \
-DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF \
-DBUILD_TESTS=OFF \
-DBUILD_opencv_python2=OFF  \
-DOPENCV_FFMPEG_SKIP_BUILD_CHECK=ON \
-DWITH_V4L=OFF \
-DWITH_FFMPEG=ON \
-DBUILD_opencv_python3=OFF ../opencv-4.x

# Build OpenCV Java shared lib
RUN make -j8

FROM debian:11 AS opencv

COPY --from=opencv-libs /usr/bin/ffmpeg /usr/bin/ffmpeg

# Big(ish) static lib from the OpenCV build. Contains all OpenCV deps.
# OpenCV JNI layer needs this to work
COPY --from=opencv-libs /lib/libopencv_java480.so /opencvlibs/
COPY --from=opencv-libs /bin/opencv-480.jar /opencvlibs/

# These are all the shared libs needed by OpenCV - not available in the Distroless container
# Copy all the /lib dir. Linux will pick up shared libs from /lib by default convention
COPY --from=opencv-libs /lib/liblzma* \
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma* \
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2* \
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error* \
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux* \
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err* \
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils* \
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.6 \
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 \
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 \
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtirpc.so.3 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavcodec.so.58 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavutil.so.56 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswscale.so.5 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat.so.58 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswresample.so.3 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavdevice.so.58 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavfilter.so.7 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavresample.so.4 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpostproc.so.55 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libraw1394.so.11 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavc1394.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librom1394.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libiec61883.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjack.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenal.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcdio_paranoia.so.2 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcdio_cdda.so.2 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdc1394.so.25 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcaca.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-14.2.so \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-server.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.5 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpocketsphinx.so.3 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsphinxbase.so.3 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbs2b.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblilv-0.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librubberband.so.2 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysofa.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflite_cmu_us_awb.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflite_cmu_us_kal.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflite_cmu_us_kal16.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflite_cmu_us_rms.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflite_cmu_us_slt.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflite.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libass.so.9 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libslang.so.2 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXss.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgbm.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblas.so.3 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblapack.so.3 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libserd-0.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsord-0.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsratom-0.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsamplerate.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so.3 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflite_usenglish.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflite_cmulex.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflite_usenglish.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvidstab.so.1.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsndio.so.7.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcdio.so.19 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcdio.so.19 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdc1394.so.25 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaom* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbluray* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo-gobject.so.2 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libchromaprint* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcodec2* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdav1d.so.4 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgme* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsm* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmfx* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmp3lame.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenCL* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjp2* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenmpt.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopus* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librabbitmq* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librsvg-2.so.2 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libshine* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnappy* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsoxr* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspeex* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsrt-gnutls.so.1.4 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh-gcrypt.so.4 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtheoradec* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtheoraenc.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtwolame* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva-drm* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libva* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvdpau* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbis* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvpx.so.6 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwavpack* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so.6 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebpmux* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ibx26460* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx26592* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxvidcore.so.4 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzvbi.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx264* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx265* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpg123* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudfread* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsodium.so.23 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpgm-5.3* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnorm.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.67 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.8 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.6 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfribidi* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.67 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmd* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie* \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXv.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1 \
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.2 \
/opencvlibs/

ENTRYPOINT ["ls", "opencvlibs"]
```